# NodeJS: Find object from array not contained in another array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays of objects:

```
var existingUsers1 = [];
    existingUsers1.push({
        "userName": "A",
        "departmentId": "1"
    });
    existingUsers1.push({
        "userName": "B",
        "departmentId": "1"
    });
    existingUsers1.push({
        "userName": "C",
        "departmentId": "1"
    });
    existingUsers1.push({
        "userName": "D",
        "departmentId": "1"
    });

var existingUsers2 = [];
    existingUsers2.push({
        "userName": "A",
        "departmentId": "1"
    });
    existingUsers2.push({
        "userName": "B",
        "departmentId": "1"
    });
```

I need to find the objects from existingUsers1 that are not present in existingUsers2. Is there any function in nodeJS that I can use to achieve this or any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var existingUsers1 = [{ userName: "A", departmentId: "1" }, { userName: "B", departmentId: "1" }, { userName: "C", departmentId: "1" }, { userName: "D", departmentId: "1" }],
    existingUsers2 = [{ userName: "A", departmentId: "1" }, { userName: "B", departmentId: "1" }],
    hash = new Set(existingUsers2.map(o => o.userName)),
    result = existingUsers1.filter(o => !hash.has(o.userName));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```